# Show contextmenu only after long press

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

I want to activate a context-menu only after left-mousedown is pressed for N seconds (e.g. 2 seconds).
If the mouse is released, the context-menu should not be shown.
I tried to use:

- setTimeout and clearTimeout - to handle the wait time.
- jquery contextmenu - for using the context-menu.

But I cannot get the expected behaviour.
What I get is a delay before showing the context-menu for the first time, but:

- if I stop pressing the mouse before the wait time, the context-menu still shows up.
- after the first time, the context-menu is shown with every click, even is the mouse is released before the wait time.

How can I condition showing the context-menu, only after the mouse is clicked for a specified time period?

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls. show your code so we can review it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lz08n1ex/97/).
It uses the methods:

```
Window.setTimeout, Window.clearTimeout,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reach it with this solution

```
const MouseDownDuration = class {
    setMouseDown() {
        this.downAt = new Date();
    }

    setMouseUp() {
        this.upAt = new Date();
    }

    get duration () {
        return this.upAt.getTime() - this.downAt.getTime()
    }
}

const contextMenu = new MouseDownDuration();


document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    contextMenu.setMouseDown();
});

document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    contextMenu.setMouseUp();

    // Log the diff in milliseconds
    console.log(contextMenu.duration);

    // Eventually dispatch a custom event
});
```

You can also see how to dispatch an event using `e.target` element by checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events